# How to do mysql_data_seek in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to reset the pointer to the first record in CodeIgniter. Consider the following greatly simplified code:

```
$query_milestones = "SELECT * FROM milestones";
$milestones       = $this->db->query($query_milestones);

foreach($milestones->result() as $milestoneRow){
    // do something
}
$milestones->data_seek(0); // <--- This gives me Fatal error.
foreach($milestones->result() as $milestoneRow){
    // do something else
}
```

This gives me:
Fatal error:  Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_result::data_seek()

How can I do a mysql_data_seek with CodeIgniter?

UPDATE: It seems VERY odd to me but resetting the pointer apparently is not necessary. The following does what I want but not what I expect:

```
$query_milestones = "SELECT * FROM milestones";
$milestones       = $this->db->query($query_milestones);

foreach($milestones->result() as $milestoneRow){
    // do something
}
// As soon as the foreach is reached, the first record is retrieved again. 
foreach($milestones->result() as $milestoneRow){
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `#$this->db->data_seek(0);` instead of `$milestones->data_seek(0);`

Comment: Good idea but no go. Fatal Error on that one also.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `$milestones->_data_seek(0);` but I have not used CodeIgniter in a while and supposedly it is a private method, at least it used to be.

Comment: This did not cause an error but it also does not appear to reset the pointer either. I looked at the core code and it should. I'm thinking that when foreach is used to loop, php is taking control and forcing the pointer to be where php wants it. To test it I put it inside the foreach and expected an endless loop but instead it looped through all the records as if it was not there.